# VPython: Wrong display in Ubuntu since visual 6 (wrong z-value check?)

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics

I have a very strange 3D-behaviour of VPython on ubuntu:

Objects that should be displayed in front or behind other objects are displayed in a wrong way!

I wrote a little python-program to illustrate this behaviour, because this program runs well on windows!

![wrong] https://www.dropbox.com/s/vhgh69jr343t6ly/curve%20ubuntu.jpg?dl=0

![OK] https://www.dropbox.com/s/refcuglz774zlr7/curve%20windows.jpg?dl=0

Both operating systems are on the same computer, using the same graphic card!

I saw this behaviour since I downloaded visual 6.0 (or was it already before that? I can't remember... I installed version 6 because I coudn't install version 5.72 / 5.74 on Ubuntu).

In the past I never had any problem with visual's graphic!

My versions of my os, progs and modules are:

- Windows 7,
  Python 2.7.2,
  wx 3.0.0.0 msw (classic),
  visual 5.74 release,
- Ubuntu 14.04,
  Python 2.7.6,
  wx 3.0.0.0 gtk2 (classic),
  visual 6.04 release

Processor:    Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4400 @ 2.20GHz × 2
Graphic Card: Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset x86/MMX/SSE2

If there is somebody who could help me... I would be VERY glad!

Uli Eggermann